# Display a fixed title (img or txt) on a Mapbox map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I don't find anything on the Mapbox documentation about this ; so I guess I've missed the logic : **is there a simple way to add a title on the map that is not affected by the zoom ?** (like the Mapbox logo at the bottom left)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `<div>` or `<pre>` element on top of the map `<div>`.

Here is an example based on https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/:

https://jsbin.com/geyejalemu/1/edit?html,output